# Zooming a part of figure contain some graphs in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, zooming

I have a figure(fig1) in matlab that it contains two graphs. I have attached it. How can I zoom in a part of the diagram?

[image]

Something like this:

[image]

I can do that for a figure with one graph. But I do not know about the figure which contains two graphs.

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/60376-how-to-make-an-inset-of-matlab-figure-inside-the-figure

Comment: What exactly is the issue when you do the same for figures with "two graphs"? Are you referring to the red and blank lines as "two graphs"?